# Error when trying to save multiples records in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

When I try to save multiples records in my database I verify before if exist one record like that with this function.

```
public boolean hasNotaFiscal(Pojo pojo) {

    String sql = "SELECT nota_fiscal.numero, nota_fiscal.tipo_emissao, d.cnpj, e.cnpj FROM nota_fiscal";
    sql = sql.concat(" INNER JOIN destinatario ON (nota_fiscal.destinatario_id = destinatario.id)");
    sql = sql.concat(" INNER JOIN emitente ON (nota_fiscal.emitente_id = emitente.id)");
    sql = sql.concat(" INNER JOIN dados_empresa e ON (e.id = emitente.dados_empresa_id)");
    sql = sql.concat(" INNER JOIN dados_empresa d ON (d.id = destinatario.dados_empresa_id)");
    sql = sql.concat(" WHERE e.cnpj = :cnpjEmitente AND d.cnpj = :cnpjDestinatario AND numero = :numero AND tipo_emissao = :tipoEmissao");

    SQLQuery query = (SQLQuery) this.createSQLQuery(sql);

    query.addEntity(NotaFiscal.class);

    query.setParameter("cnpjDestinatario", pojo.getDestinatario().getDadosEmpresa().getCnpj());
    query.setParameter("cnpjEmitente", pojo.getEmitente().getDadosEmpresa().getCnpj());
    query.setParameter("numero", pojo.getNumero());
    query.setParameter("tipoEmissao", pojo.getTipoEmissao().getIndex());

    return query.list().size() > 0;
}
```

But in the 16 record I´m getting this error...

```
Nov 28, 2013 5:39:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
Nov 28, 2013 5:39:39 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Column 'id' not found.
```

I found someome telling to set scallar method but didn´t works with me.

I´m using `mysql` 5 and `hibernate` in `Java`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after i searching a lot of things in google.

I found the solution, it was to take off the `entity class` but I need to rename the field `cnpj`.

So the code look like this.

```
@Override
public boolean hasNotaFiscal(Pojo pojo) {

    String sql = "SELECT nota_fiscal.numero, nota_fiscal.tipo_emissao, d.cnpj as cnpjDestinatario, e.cnpj as cnpjEmitente FROM nota_fiscal";
    sql = sql.concat(" INNER JOIN destinatario ON (nota_fiscal.destinatario_id = destinatario.id)");
    sql = sql.concat(" INNER JOIN emitente ON (nota_fiscal.emitente_id = emitente.id)");
    sql = sql.concat(" INNER JOIN dados_empresa e ON (e.id = emitente.dados_empresa_id)");
    sql = sql.concat(" INNER JOIN dados_empresa d ON (d.id = destinatario.dados_empresa_id)");
    sql = sql.concat(" WHERE e.cnpj = :cnpjEmitente AND d.cnpj = :cnpjDestinatario AND numero = :numero AND tipo_emissao = :tipoEmissao");

    SQLQuery query = (SQLQuery) this.createSQLQuery(sql);

    query.setParameter("cnpjDestinatario", pojo.getDestinatario().getDadosEmpresa().getCnpj());
    query.setParameter("cnpjEmitente", pojo.getEmitente().getDadosEmpresa().getCnpj());
    query.setParameter("numero", pojo.getNumero());
    query.setParameter("tipoEmissao", pojo.getTipoEmissao().getIndex());

    return query.list().size() > 0;
}
```